# Remove TextInput underline React-Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

[image]

I want to remove the underline directly under the text in the above screenshot (the second/lower underline is my own borderBottom on the TextInput).

There is a prop `underlineColorAndroid` for RN TextInput component that I believe is supposed to control this, and I even upgraded to `react-native v0.56.0` as the default value of this prop was changed to 'transparent', which is what I want.

e.g.

```
<TextInput
  onChange={this.onChange}
  value={tag}
  underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
/>
```

I have even tried changing many style attributes in `/android/app/src/main/res/values`, but nothing has worked.

How can I remove, or change the color of, the underline on Android for React-Native's TextInput (which I believe maps to Android's EditText)?

**EDIT:**
Without the upgrade to `react-native 0.56.0`, it looks like the below screenshot. So perhaps `underlineColorAndroid="transparent"` does work in v0.56.0? But then what is the remaining underline?

[image]

Comment: `underlineColorAndroid` doesn't work?

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly nope, tried that as shown above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underline right beneath the text is an Android OS keyboard feature thing, it just indicates the current word you are on, it provides a smart context prompt and if you hit delete, it'll just delete the whole word.

**TL;DR:** built-in Android feature, you can't really do anything there.

Answer (score 0):

`<TextInput underlineColorAndroid='transparent'>`

Comment: Have done this, as detailed in my question. Seems to get rid of the one underline, but not the other.